# MOSS FBA never asking for creds

Tags: sharepoint, iis, moss, forms-authentication

I've set up FBA on an extended site, added a user, verified the central admin can read the users (people picker works fine).

The problem is no matter what I try I never get asked for credentials, just get a "You are not authorized to view this page". I have a feeling its something in IIS but I've added all anonymous accounts I can think of.

If I switch the authentication type back to windows it works fine.

I've read countless how-to's and I don't think I am missing a step, they all just end with "you should now see the login page" which I am denied from.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e90fe777-4a21-4066-bd22-b931f7572e9a&DisplayLang=en and ran it on my site, determined that someone (@#$@#$) changed the IUSR password and never logged it or updated it either way it's working now and I'd recommend this tool as it solved my issue in two seconds flat!

Answer (score 0):

IF this is in IE, check your setting for User Authentication (all the way at the bottom) for the current zone in Internet Options. That happens when the setting is Automatically Logon with Current User ID and Password, rather than Prompt for User Name and Password.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the user in the FBA store is one thing, and giving that user access in SharePoint is another. Did you make the user a site owner for the site you are trying to access?